# Why inserting Google client ID make React produce the Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, google-client-login

I'm working on how to use variable from `process.env`. When I inserted the Google Client ID and `npm start`, React produce an error in browser's console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`.

The variables in `.env` that not produce an error.

```
REACT_APP_TITLE=How To React
REACT_APP_DESCRIPTION="Using .env file in React js"
```

The variable in `.env` that produce an error.

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID="000000000000-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have done. Obviously obscure your client ID.

Comment: I'm added the `.env` on above.

Comment: It's impossible to help you now, as you have not described in sufficient detail what happens. Please make a reproducible issue so that it's possible to understand

Comment: I know only if I inserted a Google Client ID variable into `.env` file and `npm start`. React produce an error in the browser's console.. Beside that I don't know.